# IP as Python associative/dictionaries array indices/keys

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to set an assoc array indices as an IP so i can track how many times they come up in packets.

```
 log = {}
 if log[str(s_addr)] < 1:
     log[str(s_addr)] = 1
 else:
     log[str(s_addr)] += 1
     if log[str(s_addr)] > 100:
         data_salary = {
             'protocol' : str(protocol),
             'source_ip': str(s_addr),
             'dest_ip': str(d_addr),
             'source_port':str(source_port),
             'dest_port': str(dest_port)
         }
         cursor.execute(add_salary, data_salary)
         cnx.commit()
         print("Logged")
```

However this is giving me a KeyError

Is there any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

It's giving you a KeyError because `log[str(s_addr)]` is undefined when you're trying to make the comparison. Try something like:

```
log = {
  str(s_addr) : 0
}
if log[str(s_addr)] < 1:
    ...
```

Comment: However, it's worth noting that given this code, `log[str(s_addr)]` is going to be reset to 0 every time; I was just addressing the KeyError. I would need a little more information about this code's greater environment in order to advise you more.

Comment: Alternatively could just make `log` a `collections.defaultdict(int)`.